# Construction of Homogenous Differential Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have to construct a homogenous differential equation of second order which has y(t) = e^t cos(t) as solution.

I know have some knowledge of how to solve (some) differential equations, but how do I construct one (systematically)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derive.

$$y'(t)=e^t\cos t-e^t\sin t=y(t)-e^t\sin t,$$
$$y^{''}(t)=y'(t)-e^t\sin t-y(t).$$

Then subtracting the second equation from the first you arrive at
  $$2y'(t)-y^{''}(t)-2y(t)=0.$$

Comment: are different ODEs possible? See Eli's answer below.

Comment: @TestGuest they are the same answer

Comment: well now yes...

Comment: my was alwayes the same

Answer (score 1):

You want $y=e^t cos(t)$ as a solution so lets take charecteristic equation to be the one with $i+1 $ as its root.

This will be your charecteristic equation $(\lambda-(i+1))(\lambda+(1-i)) \to \lambda ^2 - 2\lambda +2$.

And this is your ode  $y''-2y'+2y=0$ .